# Redirection and URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a site, with hosting, at a .co.uk domain.

I have a .com stand alone domain - with a different provider, set up with a 301 redirect to my site at .co.uk

Is there any way to write a little htaccess magic that will rewrite .co.uk to .com permanently, as standard?

Or am I going to need to transfer the domain over?

I have tried the following (and variations thereof), with no luck.
(bear in mind the only lines in question here are the first 3. I have included the latter part of the file for context, as these rules are also necessary)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^categories$          index.php?action=categories [L]
RewriteRule ^about$          index.php?action=about [L]
RewriteRule ^modelling$          index.php?action=modelling [L]
RewriteRule ^exhibitions$          index.php?action=exhibitions [L]
RewriteRule ^sales$          index.php?action=sales [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$          index.php?action=contact [L]
RewriteRule ^/$          index.php?action=homepage [L]
RewriteRule ^admin$          admin.php [L]


RewriteRule ^categories/([0-9]+)$          index.php?action=subcategories&parent_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)$          index.php?action=archive&category_id=$1 [L]
```

I would like htaccess to rewrite the url's so that they always read .com, regardless where they come from.

Currently, if I hit my .com site (domain only), it forwards to .co.uk (where the hosting is parked, along with this .htaccess file), and changes the url to .co.uk.

You could say that currently my domains are the wrong way around - i.e .co.uk is set as the main domain name, which the url will always change to regardless which url you request, due to .com forwarding there. My question is, is there a way to reverse this with .htaccess?

The code above does not change the url's at all, regardless whether I try .com or .co.uk

Comment: yes there is (check RewriteCond combined with RewriteRule)

Comment: I'm struggling to put this together correctly. Any examples?

Comment: What are you getting when you request some URLs and what are you expecting to get?